# Quasar VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework

Im using quasar together with Vite. After installing quasar with `yarn create quasar`  I get the following warning in the console.

```
__VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__ is not explicitly defined.
 You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue, which expects these 
compile-time feature flags to be globally injected via the bundler 
config in order to get better tree-shaking in the production 
bundle.
```

How can I get rid of it? I cannot find any information on where I shall define this in Quasar Framework

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This warning starts appearing after upgrading to Vue 3.4 without upgrading all other required dependencies, namely `@vitejs/plugin-vue`, which should be upgraded to ^5.0.0.  This is documented under [Potential Actions Needed](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-4#potential-actions-needed) when upgrading to Vue 3.4.

With Quasar, you can not upgrade this package directly since it's not a top-level dependency of Quasar projects.  Until the Quasar team releases an update, you will need to set the flag yourself

**quasar.config.js**

```js
build: {
  extendViteConf(viteConf) {
    viteConf.define.__VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__ = false
  },
}
```

Comment: Any harm or benefits setting it to true?

Comment: It's a flag for debugging hydration mismatch errors in production https://vuejs.org/api/compile-time-flags#VUE_PROD_HYDRATATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS